# How can I set content-type to application/JSON in online API consoles like Apigee and Hurl.it

Tags: json, post, https, ibm-cloud, apigee

Where would I put something along the lines of content-type = application/json?

My options are destination and type (GET, POST, etc.), authentication, headers, parameters, and body. My body looks like this (it's a push notification request via Bluemix):

```
{
  "message": {
    "alert": "Hello world"
  },
  "target": {
    "deviceIds": [
      "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "apns": {
      "type": "MIXED",
      "category": "CATEGORY_NAME"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting HTTP error 415: Unsupported media type. Content-type = text/plain

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, in case anyone needs it:

I added a header with name: "Content-Type" and value "application/json; charset utf8"